How do I stop the following Cargo Build Error
Im getting the following error and was wondering how one is able to fix it
enter error: invalid table header

duplicate key package in document root
--> Cargo.toml:21:1
|
21 | [package]
| ^
|
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CodeWork\Store> code here
